# Invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, class

In order to explain my problem I used 3 classes: `Actions`, `Triggers`, and `Combine`.

`Actions` simulates an action function, that is defined externally.

`Triggers` has that function that needed to be executed.

`Combine` combines `Actions` and `Triggers`.

Now, `void combine_funcs()` is a member function of `Combine` class, when the match between `Triggers` and `Actions` happen -> passing a function to be executed.

Here `void combine_funcs()` is show with `std::bind`, but is was also tested straight foreward.

Error outsput is given below code.

```
class Actions
{
  typedef void (*cb_func)(uint8_t resaon);

private:
  cb_func exter_func;

public:
  void get_external_func(cb_func func)
  {
    exter_func = func;
  }
  void callAction(uint8_t i)
  {
    exter_func(i);
  }
};

class Triggers
{
public:
  void this_is_external_func(uint8_t i)
  {
    Serial.println(i);
  }
};

class Combine
{
public:
  Actions a;
  Triggers b;

  void combine_funcs()
  {
    a.get_external_func(std::bind(&Triggers::this_is_external_func, this,std::placeholders::_1));
  }
  void loop()
  {
    if (millis() > 10000)
    {
      a.callAction();
    }
  }
};

Combine combo;

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Start!");
  combo.combine_funcs();
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  combo.loop();
}
```

Compilation output:

```
/Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino: In member function 'void Combine::combine_funcs()':
    sketch_jul26a:36:34: error: cannot convert 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Triggers::*)(unsigned char), Combine*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type' to 'Actions::cb_func' {aka 'void (*)(unsigned char)'}
       36 |     a.get_external_func(std::bind(&Triggers::this_is_external_func, this,std::placeholders::_1));
          |                         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                                  |
          |                                  std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Triggers::*)(unsigned char), Combine*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type
    /Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino:9:34: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void Actions::get_external_func(Actions::cb_func)'
        9 |   void get_external_func(cb_func func)
          |                          ~~~~~~~~^~~~
    /Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino: In member function 'void Combine::loop()':
    sketch_jul26a:42:20: error: no matching function for call to 'Actions::callAction()'
       42 |       a.callAction();
          |                    ^
    /Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino:13:8: note: candidate: 'void Actions::callAction(uint8_t)'
       13 |   void callAction(uint8_t i)
          |        ^~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino:13:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
    exit status 1
    cannot convert 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Triggers::*)(unsigned char), Combine*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type' to 'Actions::cb_func' {aka 'void (*)(unsigned char)'}
```

**EDIT_1 : Change `Combine` class to inherete other classes**

```
class Combine : public Actions, Triggers
{
public:
  void combine_funcs()
  {
    get_external_func(this_is_external_func);
  }
  void loop()
  {
    if (millis() > 10000)
    {
      callAction(13);
    }
  }
```

yeilds same error:

```
/Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino: In member function 'void Combine::combine_funcs()':
sketch_jul26a:33:23: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void Triggers::this_is_external_func(uint8_t)'
   33 |     get_external_func(this_is_external_func);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino:22:8: note: declared here
   22 |   void this_is_external_func(uint8_t i)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino: At global scope:
sketch_jul26a:60:6: error: redefinition of 'void setup()'
   60 | void setup()
      |      ^~~~~
/Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino:46:6: note: 'void setup()' previously defined here
   46 | void setup()
      |      ^~~~~
sketch_jul26a:68:6: error: redefinition of 'void loop()'
   68 | void loop()
      |      ^~~~
/Users/guydvir/Dropbox/Arduino/sketch_jul26a/sketch_jul26a.ino:54:6: note: 'void loop()' previously defined here
   54 | void loop()
      |      ^~~~
exit status 1
invalid use of non-static member function 'void Triggers::this_is_external_func(uint8_t)'

};
```

Comment: Does this Q+A help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72450270/10292145

Comment: @VE7JRO can you explain why do I need a void* ?

Comment: why not set the object as a parameter?

Comment: @Juraj i tried, with no luck

Comment: @guyd - When I try to compile your code, I get different errors. I am using a different compiler than you are, so my first error leads me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261013/bind-is-not-a-member-of-std In the Arduino world, they point me here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/include-functional-error/397411  The only questions I have for you is, why are you writing your code this way, and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why not using class inheritance, for example, `class Combine public Action {}`? However, solution aside, don't create classes for the sake of creating classes, all three of your classes are not necessary or should belong to somewhere else as methods.

Comment: I'll try to explain my bigger problem: 
I have 2 classes I've written and tested. One is a Button-Read states including timeouts class, and second class deals with turning ON/Off lights including PWM lights. BOTH are used and tested before. Third library combines both including have on-flash parameters and MQTT command (as some kind og a wrapper) even have multiple instances of my third class.

I want to use all my 3 classes as a legacy that works, rather that re-write it all

Comment: I meant the parameter type should by a class and you pass an object there and execute the function on that object. a member function must be invoked on an object, that is why you can use that function as a parameter. it doesn't know on what object it should be executed.

Comment: @Juraj can you explain using example ?

Comment: maybe later today

Comment: You need to call `this_is_external_func()` on an object, but you don't provide one in `callAction()`. I see two alternatives: 1) Provide an object to call the method on. 2) Make the method a class function, which does not need an object.

Comment: @hcheung took your advice for inherete (see edit 1), but same results

Comment: the return type of bind is not the same type as the type of the original function

Comment: @Juraj Can you point ?

Comment: I changed your sketch with `auto f = std:bind....` and `a.get_external_func(f);` and the error message is a little clearer.

Comment: @Juraj - GREAT!!! that was the first lead I got what did I do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the return type of bind is not the same type as the type of the original function so you can't set it with `void get_external_func(cb_func func)`.

But it looks like in X->Y problem. If you do OOP, use objects.

I take the sketch in the question as a test so I want comment on other parts and how to do them properly. I just made minimal changes to pass the object and call the method (member function) with the object.

```
class Triggers
{
public:
  void func(uint8_t i)
  {
    Serial.println(i);
  }
};

class Actions
{
  Triggers* trigers;
  
public:
  void set_triggers(Triggers* t)
  {
    trigers = t;
  }
  
  virtual void callAction(uint8_t i)
  {
    trigers->func(i);
  }
};

class Combine
{
public:
  Actions a;
  Triggers b;

  void combine_funcs()
  {
    a.set_triggers(&b);
  }
  void loop()
  {
    if (millis() < 10000)
    {
      a.callAction(1);
    }
  }
};

Combine combo;

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Start!");
  combo.combine_funcs();
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  combo.loop();
}
```